# How to show a r bookdown book in a page in jekyll powered github blog?

Tags: r, jekyll, github-pages, bookdown, jekyll-bootstrap

I have created a jekyll powered blog hosted on github which serves as an online repository of code/learning I find interesting. The blog is hosted [here](https://sn248.github.io/).

I want to add an `r` based `bookdown` book which has the following address

`sn248.github.io/tutorials/my-book`

I have created the `bookdown` based book in a separate repository, but I am not sure where to put it in the directory structure of my blog and how to render it properly as a `gitbook`.

In case it is required, the example `bookdown` based book is this [repository](https://github.com/sn248/dplyr_gitbook). I have tried to understand the instructions given in the `bookdown` manual [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/github.html), but I don't think I understand them clearly enough to render this book as a sub-page in my blog.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks

SN248

Comment: Do you need it under your blog? You can just link to it in its repo, like https://sn248.github.io/dplyr_gitbook/_book/

Comment: @Frank - Thanks for the message. I guess I could link it like that, but I wanted one repository for the entire blog and also don't like the `_book` part in the link.